# Exposing Cocoa Object to JS Scripting Environment via WebScriptObject

Tags: javascript, cocoa, webkit

I see there are a couple of similar questions, but this is a bit more basic.

I am trying to expose a simple Cocoa object via WebScriptObject to a WebView, hopefully allowing the page to send messages to the Cocoa object. The documentation on this is very clear, but for some reason I can't get it to work. Wondering if you'll have a look...

Here is the Object that I'm loading into the scripting environment.

```
@interface Client : NSObject {

     NSString *test;

}

@implementation Client

- (id)init {

    self = [super init];
    test = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hey Simon"];
    return self;

}

- (NSString *)test {

    return test;
}
```

Then I'm loading that object in the WebView's frameLoad delegate, with:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView didClearWindowObject:(WebScriptObject *)windowObject forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {

    Client *_client = [[Client alloc] init];
    [windowObject setValue:_client forKey:@"client"];

}
```

On the JS side of things, I am just doing something really basic:

```
if( 'client' in window ) {

var client = window.client;

console.log( '---' );

console.log( 'client.test(): ' + client.test() );

console.log( '---' );

}
```

The JS console says TypeError: Result of expression 'client.test' [undefined] is not a function.

A couple of things. I know the object is being loaded into the scripting environment properly because it wouldn't pass the conditional plus I can see a description with:

```
console.log( 'Client object: ' + client )
```

But I just don't know how to expose my cocoa methods properly. Looking at what I've said above, is there some problem with how I am implementing the methods in my class, or calling them in JS?

Thanks in advance,
Alec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was right there in the docs. :(

You have to implement + (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)aSelector on the object you are passing in.

So in my case, I had to write

```
+ (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)aSelector

{
    if (aSelector == @selector(test)) return NO;
    return YES;
}
```